# How to rerun a method passed as an input property to an angular component?

Tags: angular

I need to pass a calculated value to an Angular component. Currently I'm doing it like this:

```
<component [value]="getCalculatedValue()"></component>
```

The problem is that the base for the calculated value changes every minute so the calculated value must also be updated.

How can I tell angular to run the `getCalculatedValue` method again for every component that it uses?

As the component is an external component I would prefer a way without modifying the component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the ViewChild you can have access to the external component inside the .ts file of your host component. Where you can anytime change the @Input() properties of the external component. Something like this

```
<component #myComponent [value]="getCalculatedValue()"></component>
```

In your ts file you can create a reference to your external component through [ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild). Like this

```
  @ViewChild('myComponent') public myComponent: Component;
```

*Please note that 'myComponent' refers to template-reference variable referred with # in the .html part of your host component and 'Component' means the class name of your external component.*

Now you can change the @Input() properties at any event, callback, method etc. Something like this

```
myComponent.value = getCalculatedValue();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of passing a function (which returns a value) to the component, you should return the value instead.

HTML:

```
<component [value]="value"></component>
```

TS:

```
export class CurrentComponent implements OnInit {
    value: any;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.value = getCalculatedValue();

        // insert functionality to recalculate value on either a timer, Observable, etc...
    }
}
```

Functions in an input are also rerun on change detection

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-current',
    templateUrl: './current.component.html',
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class CurrentComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        // call this.cd.detectChanges() when you want an update
    }

}
```